# How get Json nested elements

Tags: c#, json

i've this json and i need an help to iterate over Elenco.

This is my json

```
var json = @"
{
 {
    "Id": 0,
    "Point": "123",
    "Elenco": [
         {
           //useless fields
           //...
            {
             "values_": {
                "flat": [
                 1.0, 2.0
                ]
              },
            "idPoint": "123",
          },
       },
       {
        //useless fields
        //...
        {
            "values_": {
                "flat": [
                    3.0, 6.0
                ]
            },
            "idPoint": "1234",
        }, 
      },
      {
        //Other fields here like values, flat and idPoint for x times
       },     
    ]
  }
 }";
```

I can easily get Id and Point with

```
JObject object = JObject.Parse(json);
string point = (string)jsonObject["Point"];
```

but i need to take **flat** and **idPoint** and i don't know how do that.

I also need to iterate over Elenco and I have to find which point equals idPunto.

How can i do? Thanks

Comment: IMHO create classes that represent your `json` and then deserialize the `json` to it's respectful object/s; it will fix your issue's, more manageable and help prevent potential issue's later.

Comment: @zaggler can't i get Elenco using Newtonsoft.Json library? I should do how u said but i prefer one solution with that library or smth.

Comment: Newtonsoft will work just fine.

Comment: You don't even need to hand-craft the model classes. [Json2Csharp](https://json2csharp.com/) comes in handy.

Comment: @peter powerful tools, i think im going with that.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to achieve what you are trying to do is go via the route of creating the models that represent your json structure and then use a simple json serializer/deserializer library like [JSON.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to deserialize it and access easily its properties.

From what i see, your json model looks something like this:

```
public class JsonModel
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Point {get; set;}
   public IEnumerable<JsonModel2> Elenco {get;set;}
}

public class JsonModel2
{
   //useless fields
   public JsonModel3 SomeProperty{get; set;}
}


public class JsonModel3
{
   //useless fields
   // i am assuming here that it is a dictionary as it wasnt clear from the json
   public Dictionary<string, JsonModel4> DictProperty{get; set;}
}

public class JsonModel4
{
   //useless fields
   public IEnumerable<float> Flat{get; set;}
}
```

i am pretty sure i made a mistake here or there in the way i defined the models above, as i feel that the Json itself is not totally correct or is missing a few key elements. Nonetheless, once you define the models correctly with all the elements in your json as a part of your model, you can simply then use

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonModel>(json);
```

this will nicely parse and populate the model values correctly, thereby allowing you to iterate over the model properties like a regular c# object.